# jquery picklist remove items

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using jquery picklist in my web application. I need to refresh it's content from time to time, and each time I do this all the items are duplicate in the list.

The code I use is this:

```
addAssetsToModal = function(assets){
        $("#pckAssets").empty();
        assets.each(function(asset){
            $("#pckAssets").pickList("insert",
                {
                    value: asset._id._oid,
                    label: asset.name,
                    selected: isAssetOnDashboard(asset._id._oid)
                });
        });
    },
```

Before to add items I'd like to remove any existing item.

My tries:

```
$("#pckAssets").empty(); //doesn't work
$('#pckAssets option').remove();  //doesn't work
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to clear container or target list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find any way looking in the [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-picklist/w/list) for clear the elements.

Consider that the plugin starts from a select, but renders two differents ul-li's for source and target list.
So if you clear your select object you'll clear the select, but not the already rendered ul-li's

I thinks there are two ways:

1. **destroy and reinit**: you can destroy and reinit the control; the lists will
   be cleared as consequence (the widget must implement the destroy methos, and it does)
2. **clear the list**: clear the two ul-li's using jQuery:

First way (I prefer this):

```
$("#basic").pickList("destroy");
$("#basic").pickList();
```

Second way (a bit hacky):

```
$('.pickList_sourceList li').remove();
$('.pickList_targetList li').remove();
```

Here is a working fiddle with the two ways: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/GVKFB/

Comment: The first way doesn't work, I get "destroy is not a function" error. I didn't have time to check it so I did the second way witch works perfect. Thanks Edward.

Comment: @ZelterAdy glad to help you! But the 1st way works, check the fiddle :-)

Comment: I also got an exception `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_destroy' `, when using the first way , so I tried the second way, the problem then is I cannot re initailize the picklist because calling `$("#basic").pickList();` doesnt add it back

Comment: I think I got it. We need to insert the values again into the picklist using `insert`method